# tar error: executed tar command with same output-file name as source-file

Tags: linux, zip, tar, recovery, data-recovery

Instead of executing the following command:

> tar -zcvf file.tgz fileX

I executed the following instead:

> tar -zcvf fileX fileX

I encountered the following message on the screen: 
tar: fileX: File shrank by 199917 bytes; padding with zeros

Now I see garbage data in fileX. Even when extracting the file fileX, I still see garbage.

> i.e. tar -zxvf fileX

Is there any way to recover the data (using either linux commands or through hard-disk memory scans, etc)